# TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer while creating subplots

Tags: python

I'm about to make subplots for my cartpole problem, but i got typeerror: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I've tried to change it using 'len' function but it still doesn't work. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? The code is shown below:

```
x_array = np.array(x_array)
x_hat_array = np.array(x_hat_array)
t_array = np.array(t_array)

subplots = []
datapoints, state_num, _ = _, x_array.shape, _

for i in range(0,state_num):
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  subplots.append(ax)

for i in range(0,state_num):
  subplots[i].plot(t_array[:], x_array[:, i, 0])

plt.show()
```

Comment: `datapoints, state_num, _ = _, x_array.shape, _` is weird: why the two underscores on the right? Furthermore, you're assigning `datapoints` to `_`, which doesn't contain anything. What's your goal for that line?

Comment: While it is unclear what your precise goal is, you probably want `datapoints, state_num, _ = x_array.shape`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've already taken the [tour], great! For questions about error message, please always include a [mre] (the word "minimal" is important here - any lines after the error are not relevant for the question and might only distract from it), and the full traceback, which shows us in which line the problem occurred. Also please state what you were expecting on that line. You could [edit] your question to add this information. Thanks in advance.